# JAX-RS Client Connection Timeout Handling in Interceptor

Tags: cxf, jax-rs

I have added the below config in my client application context xml:

```
<bean id="customTimeoutConfigInterceptor" class="com.hs18.inventory.client.interceptor.CustomTimeoutConfigInterceptor" />
<jaxrs:client id="inventoryServiceEndPoint"
              address="http://$INVENTORY_CLIENT{inventory.api.host}:$INVENTORY_CLIENT{inventory.api.port}/api/1"
              serviceClass="com.inventory.common.InventoryService"
              inheritHeaders="true">
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="hs18ResponseExceptionMapper" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
    <jaxrs:inFaultInterceptors>
        <ref bean="customTimeoutConfigInterceptor" />
    </jaxrs:inFaultInterceptors>
</jaxrs:client>
```

when the client times out i want to put the request in a message queue, I am trying this through CustomTimeoutConfigInterceptor class. But the `handleMessage` method is never invoked. Below is the code.

```
public class CustomTimeoutConfigInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

    @Resource
    InventoryServiceAsync inventoryServiceAsync;

    public CustomTimeoutConfigInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PREPARE_SEND_ENDING);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        Exception exception = message.getContent(Exception.class);
        if(exception.getMessage().equals("Connection Refused")){
            if(message.getContent(List.class) != null && !message.getContent(List.class).isEmpty()){
                Object request = message.getContent(List.class).get(0);
                if(request.getClass().getAnnotation(Command.class) != null){
                    inventoryServiceAsync.sendCommand((ICommand)request);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this for a JAX-RS client reaching out to some external endpoint? If so, I can tell a couple of things:

1. The connection timeout or client timeout happen on the "out" part of the communications stack, so you may want to set it on the `outFaultInterceptors` instead
2. From the previous point follows that the phase set on your interceptor constructor also needs to be updated, I have tried setting it to `Phase.POST_STREAM` and seems to be working.